# IndexOutOfBoundsException: with two LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

So am trying to remove a multiple words from a LinkedList from a  given indexs on LinkedList as well. But am getting

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException:
```

am trying to do that:

```
    LinkedList<Integer> List_Of_Index = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<String> list_Of_Words = new LinkedList<>();


    List_Of_Index.add(0);
    List_Of_Index.add(2);

    list_Of_Words.add("remove");
    list_Of_Words.add("dont");
    list_Of_Words.add("remove");

    for (int numb:List_Of_Index){
        list_Of_Words.remove(numb);
    }
```

Comment: After removing element at index 0, list will contain 2 elements. That will also affect indexes.

Comment: @Adam Tr. can you give us a bit more context of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

As you removed one element of the List at the first iteration of the loop, the list that contained two elements contains a single element at the second iteration and referencing the index `2` is not valid.
Whereas `list_Of_Words.remove(2)` that throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You could use a counter to count the number of removal and use it to decrement the index to remove :

```
 int removal = 0;
 for (int numb:List_Of_Index){
        list_Of_Words.remove(numb-removal);
        removal++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not remove the element at index 2 in the list_Of_Words....
the list_Of_Words has 2 elements only...

Answer (score 0):

After first iteration in cycle yout list of words will have size 2(last index 1)